# sql embedded in c program ranking several tables

Tags: sql, c

I'm writing a SQL embedded in C program with tables below:

```
table index:id, xx

table a:id, year, yy

table b:id, year, zz

table c:id, year, vv
```

id in a,b,c belong to id in index

Then how to select all the id order by year?

Comment: Can the same id exist in more than one of a,b,c? Some sample data might help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is not very clear about what you are after.  Superficially, one possible answer might be:

```
SELECT i.id, i.xx, a.year, a.yy
  FROM index AS i
  JOIN a ON i.id = a.id
UNION
SELECT i.id, i.xx, b.year, b.zz
  FROM index AS i
  JOIN b ON i.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT i.id, i.xx, c.year, c.vv
  FROM index AS i
  JOIN c ON i.id = c.id
ORDER BY year, id;
```

If all of tables A, B, and C join to a single row in Index, then there are alternative queries (using more joins, possibly some of them being LEFT OUTER JOIN).  If the columns represented by `yy`, `zz` and `vv` are not compatible, then you need to specify what to do with them (or simply leave them out of the query).